# UINavigationBar appearance + iOS 13 Dark Mode - How to set app wide color?

Tags: ios, ios13, ios-darkmode

In iOS 12 and before I used `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor...]` to set a app wide background color for all NavBars.

In iOS 13 I would like to do the same while supporting Dark Mode. In the apps Asset Catalog I defined a named Color `NavBarBackground` and specified both a `Any appearance` and `Dark appearance` color.

If the Dark Mode is disabled the correct `Any` color is used. However when Dark Mode is enabled the specified `Dark` color is ignored and all NavBar appear in plain black...

However, if I set the background color of a NavBar manually in IB to `NavBarBackground` this one NavBar shows the correct color both in Normal and in Dark Mode.

**So, how to use `[UINavigationBar appearance]` together with Dark Mode and named colors?**

Comment: add and try this in your appdelegate `if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {       
            // disable dark mode
           window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
               }` it will change the light to entire app

Comment: Thanks but this not what I meant. I want to see different color in Normal and in Dark Mode. Problem is, that in Dark Mode it shows the default color black instead of the specified one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iOS 13's new appearance API:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance

Example:

```
let style = UINavigationBarAppearance()
style.backgroundColor = .red
style.barTintColor = UIColor(named: "my_colour")!

navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = style
navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = ...
navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = ...
```

Comment: How can you set barTintColor property ? , I get error as UINavigationBarAppearance has no barTintColor property

Comment: In order to set the navigation bar's background color, you need to initialize the « backgroundColor » property on the « UINavigationBarAppearance » instance.